# Team Foundation Server API:

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to connect to my TFS server that is hosted online, by following the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958(v=vs.120).aspx

Unfortunately I keep running into the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: HTTP code 403: Tunnel or SSL Forbidden

I'm using the example exactly as it is given on the link above. I've literally only changed the location of my server to https://myusername.visualstudio.com:8080/

I've googled this problem to no end and cannot find a solution. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to access TFS using HTTPS over a non-secure port. If you try not using HTTPS does 8080 work then?

Comment: So when I remove the https and change it to "http://myusername.visualstudio.com:80/", I get the TFS31002 exception, "Unable to connect to this server (404)". I understand this is a not found exception?

Comment: try http://myusername.visualstudio.com:8080/, 8080 is the default port for TFS.

If you follow your example you'll see that it says port 8080 is the default port. It also shows the url as an HTTP url. If you know your TFS url is HTTPS, try,

https://myusername.visualstudio.com:443/ that should be the default secure port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `https://myusername.visualstudio.com:8080/`. So suppose you are using VSTS instead of on-premises TFS.

**For VSTS there is no 8080 port**. You just need to use the server url directly such as `https://myuserame.visualstudio.com`

A sample code for your reference:

```
 Uri collectionUri = new Uri("https://myusername.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");

    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, credential);
    teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```